# Axios Request From Vue/Nuxt App Timed Out, No Response From Server, But Same Curl Request Gets Response

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt application which makes requests to an IIS server running NodeJS as an API. The IIS server is set to only accept requests from the frontend Vue application server (ports 80 and 443).

When I run the below from the command line on the frontend server I get a proper response and can see the request hit the IIS backend server via logs:

```
//This WORKS
curl --cacert certbundle.crt https://xx.xx.xx.xx/cost/woapprovedqueue
```

I'm making a seemingly similar request with Axios in my Nuxt application on the same frontend server where I ran the curl request but I don't get any response from the server and the request times out after some time with the error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

When I copy the failed executed request from Chrome DevTools as cURL I get the following:

```
curl 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx/cost/woapprovedqueue' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Referer: https://xxx.yyy.com/' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

If I take the above curl command to the frontend again and add my `--cacert certbundle.crt`, it works.

**What do I need to do to make this request work with Nuxt/Axios? Is it an SSL/Certificate issue?** I'm leaning towards "no" since I don't get ANY response and nothing shows in the backend API server logs. You'd think we would at least get a cert issue response.

I have a file in `plugins/axios.js`:

```
export default function ({ $axios, store, app }) {
  $axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
  });
}
```

I load the plugin with this in nuxt.config.js: `plugins: [ '@/plugins/axios' ]`

I have an axios baseURL in nuxt.config.js: `axios: { baseURL: 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx' }`

On my .vue page I have the following which makes the request:

```
//This does NOT seem to work. I get no response, timed out, and nothing in server logs.
 this.queue = await this.$axios.$get('/cost/woapprovedqueue');
```

Any and all help will be VERY much appreciated as I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. :)

Update, providing the fetch query copied from Google Chrome Dev Tools:

```
fetch("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/cost/woapprovedqueue", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"89\", \"Chromium\";v=\"89\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0"
  },
  "referrer": "https://xxx.yyy.com/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

Comment: So it fails on client side, doesn't it? Did you try to copy the request for fetch api the same way as you did for curl and run it in browser and node?

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for your help! I've pasted the fetch results in the question above. I'll try to run this from within my Nuxt application to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was related to HTTPS/SSL. I needed to set up and use a proxy. I was getting a CORS related issue which only showed up when inspecting the network events in Firefox (Chrome did not show this level of detail for some reason). These are the settings that eventually worked in nuxt.config.js:

```
  axios: {
    https: true,
    proxy: true,
    prefix: '/api/',
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: process.env.API_BASE_URL, secure: false, pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} },
  },
```